# Schema.org 'mpn' for product variations

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I have an ecommerce site and I am trying to make sure everything is structured correctly and am not sure what to do for the `mpn` value.

I have different variations of products that each have their own MPN, however, they exist on my site in one product page, with a drop down to select the variation that the user wants.

Should I be adding all MPNs to the structured data? Or how should the information be structured in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each variant should be its own [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) (or [`ProductModel`](https://schema.org/ProductModel)). Then each `Product`/`ProductModel` would have one [`mpn`](https://schema.org/mpn) value.

If one `Product` is used for all variants, it wouldn’t be possible to convey how the products differ (or that there are variants in the first place), and others couldn’t make statements about a specific variant.

For example, if one `ProductModel` is used for a shirt that gets offered in two variations, there is no way to convey which `name`/`color`/`mpn` belong together (it’s one product model with two names, two colors, and two MPNs):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProductModel",
  "name": ["Blue shirt", "Red shirt"],
  "color": ["Red", "Blue"],
  "mpn": ["23", "24"]
}
```

So, there should be two `ProductModel` items instead:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProductModel",
  "@id": "#p24",
  "name": "Blue shirt",
  "color": "Blue",
  "mpn": "24",
  "isSimilarTo": {"@id": "#p23", "@type": "ProductModel"}
}
```

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProductModel",
  "@id": "#p23",
  "name": "Red shirt",
  "color": "Red",
  "mpn": "23",
  "isSimilarTo": {"@id": "#p24", "@type": "ProductModel"}
}
```

Comment: Could multiple Offers be used as the variants, each with an mpn?